# Did Captain America die in the Infinity War comic series?

Tags: marvel, comics, captain-america

I heard that Chris Evans won’t be playing Captain America after the Infinity War movie, so I’m assuming they’re gonna kill Steve Rogers in the movie.

But did he die in the Infinity War comic series?

If he died, then was he revived later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Infinity War movies appear to more likely be based on the Infinity Gauntlet series.

According to http://comicvine.gamespot.com/articles/the-many-deaths-of-captain-america/1100-149407/ Captain America does appear to die in issue 4 (it is a little bit unclear in the comic apparently).

He was of course revived later on as he is still appearing in comics (and like all the A-list marvel heroes and villains, is likely to continue that way).

Answer (score 5):

### In the *Infinity War* story, no. In the *Infinity Gauntlet*, yes - well, probably.

Within the actual *[Infinity War comic series](http://marvel.com/comics/series/2024/infinity_war_1992)*, Captain America does not die. He is one of a number of heroes replaced by evil doppelgangers, but the real Captain America is held trapped.

The *Infinity War* movies are said to be based on the *[Infinity Gauntlet](http://marvel.com/comics/series/2023/infinity_gauntlet_1991)* event series of comic books, which the *War* series, is a sequel to.

It is true that Captain America was defeated during the event, specifically in [issue 4](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/9289/infinity_gauntlet_1991_4). What is slightly unclear is whether or not he dies.

By this point, Thanos has been defeating heroes left and right. Some of them are clearly mentioned as dying. Moments before his own defeat, Cap comments on Thanos murdering Cyclops. Thanos slaps Cap with the back of his hand, laying him out.

[image: talk to the back of the hand]

[image: cap, get up!]

Strange discusses the defeat of the heroes, but does not seem to have specifics on individual fates.

[image: oh noes!]

He does end up searching for survivors, but only finds five. Cap is not among them.

[image: The Furious Five]

In the final issue of the event ([Issue 6](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/9289/infinity_gauntlet_1991_6)), Nebula uses the power of the Gauntlet and the gems to undo everything Thanos had done in the past day, including all of the deaths and destruction. Whatever Cap's fate was, is now undone.

[image: CTRL-Z CTRL-Z CTRL-Z!!!]

Cap is seen in the montage of everyone restored, but images of some of the survivors are also shown.

[image: What are you so happy about?]